# Determining GC run time from JMX data

Tags: java, jmx

Is it possible to determine the runtime percentage of the garbage collection from JMX data?

Currently, I'm retrieving: `MarkSweep.GarbageCollector.CollectionTime`, `Scavenge.GarbageCollector.CollectionTime`, `OperatingSystem.ProcessCpuTime` over JMX.

If I sum the two (and only?) GC collection times and divide that by the process time, does that give me a valid process time used by the GC? Or is there more to it?

I tried using this and I was finding the values range from 0 to 80000%, which obviously does not seem right.